# Let G be an r -regular graph with n vertices and m edges. Prove a simple algebraic relation between r , n, and m.

Tags: graph-theory

I know that it for any regular graph $r_{n}$ that we can show a relation between r, n, m. However, I'm not sure how to find or prove this relation. I assume that the relation will be something like $$r_{k} = n_{k} + \frac{m_{k}(m_{k}-1)}{2}$$

However, I'm really not so sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From each vertex go out $r$ edges, but this way we count twice each edge, so the number of edges is
$$m=\frac {rn}2$$